# Is this way to deal with errors safe in PHP ? Is it idiomatic?

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm writing a lot of code like this in a few of my functions :

```
$f = fopen($fname);

if ($f === false) {
    throw new Exception("cannot open $fname");
}
```

This is verbose when you deal with a lot of file to open & deal with. I'm wondering if this can work without any unforeseen bad side-effect :

```
$f = fopen($fname) or die("cannot open $fname");
```

This is idiomatic in Perl, but is this correct in PHP ? Is there another, better way to do it ? It seems valid, but I know PHP can bite you in a lot of unexpected ways.

Comment: You can do that, but it's generally better to handle it a little more gracefully via an error handler. It's a little jarring to users to get a white screen with just an error.

Comment: at least with the exception version you have the capability to catch that exception farther up the execution chain. die() will simply abort the entire script right there with any way to trap it.

Comment: That's right, a non-verbose syntax that throws exception would be much better, but I don't think `$f = foo() or throw new Exception()` is valid :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to opt for something like:

```
if(!($f = @fopen($fname, 'r'))) {
    throw new Exception("cannot open $fname");
}
```

The perl-style is fine too, although I believe fopen will raise errors.

Comment: That's a good solution as it throws exceptions rather than dying ; and, thanks for reminding me to use the `@` symbol in that context to avoid having to deal with the `E_WARNING` too in case of error.

Comment: Most of the time, `@` is a bad idea (it makes debugging harder, and the error is still thrown [silently] so it has high overhead).  But with library functions like `fopen`, where errors are a sort of "expected exception", suppressing the error lends itself to more concise and expressive code.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I make all the code as a function that can possibly throw an exception. Then call that function catching exceptions. Upon receipt of an exception if it is the live (production) generate an appropriate page and log details. Otherwise (testing/development) put those details onto the page.